# Problems with running ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to send a php request without reloading using ajax. However I don't think I understand ajax well. I tried looking at w3school sample code and tried to come up with a solution for this :

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "led.php?state=1", true);
xhttp.send();  
</script>

<button class="button" onclick = "loadDoc()">LED ON</button>

</br>
</br>
<script>
function loaddoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "led.php?state=0", true);
xhttp.send();
</script>

<button class="button" onclick "loaddoc()">LED OFF</button>
```

I honestly don't know where I am going wrong. When I click a button, a php request is sent. But right now this is clearly not working.

Can anyone help?

Regards

PHP code :

```
<?php

$onoffdata = $_GET["state"];

$textfile = "LED_data.txt";
$fileLocation = "$textfile";
$fh = fopen($fileLocation, 'w') or die("Error opening file!");

$stringToWrite = "$onoffdata";
fwrite($fh,$stringToWrite);

fclose($fh);

header("Location:index.html");
?>
```

Comment: What does your led.php do? basically your led.php will process the parameter "state".

Comment: The led.php basically changes values on another website

Comment: I assume you have LED_data.txt on your server, after you put the missing  close brackets as @noyanc answered open the LED_data_txt there you should see a 1 or 0 inside the file. and  also check if you have a permission to open and write on LED_data.txt

Comment: I did exactly what noyanc did however it does not send the state request anylonger

Comment: you cannot use headers to redirect when using ajax requests and you may wanna open the the browser network inspector to see the status and the text resulting from the request you may find some php errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I honestly don't know where I am going wrong..." => You are actually only doing part of the job there. So let me backtrack a bit:
Breaking XMLHttpRequest lifecycle into steps, you need to:

1. Instantiate the XMLHttpRequest Object; which is what you did with your `var xhttp = ...` assignment.
2. Add Event Listener(s). This is where you basically tell it what to do at every stage (I should probably say `state` here) of making your request for you. As a summary here, there are five `readyStates` you could listen for. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)
3. Initiate the request which is what you did with the `xttp.open(...)`
4. Then you send the request. That's what you did with your `xttp.send()` as you may have guessed.

So back to the step you are missing.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
```

You want to do this between your `var http = ...` and your `xhttp.open`.

That chunk is basically saying "hey xttp whenever your [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) changes (from 0 to 4), execute this function.  Now the function itself is pretty simple in this case, however pay attention to the conditional.
`this.readyState == 4` is checking if the request is `done` - that's when you get your full `response`

AND

`this.status == 200` is checking if all is good. You could search for `http status codes` for the various values `status` can be.

In a nutshell, that check is to ensure request is completed and all went well before attempting to do stuff with the `responseText`. In that W3Schools [example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first), they are setting the innerHTML of an element in the DOM to what was returned from the server. Essentially doing something with the result of the xmlhttp request. In your code snippet, you are only sending the request and not listening for response, let alone do anything with it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On your led.php put a code `<?php $_GET['state'];?>` then open your browsers inspector and go to the network tab, on the right side you will see a preview tab this will return what led.php outputs in your case , 1 or 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First test that the led.php works as intended by going to led.php?state=1. this is to test that the page is not dying. If the page is not dying then open the file and check to see if it says 1. using the code below try and turn off the led and then check the contents of the file hopefully it should be 0.

```
<script>
function setState(state) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "led.php?state="+state, true);
        xhttp.send();
    } 
</script>

<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setState(1)">LED ON</button>

</br>
</br>

<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setState(0)">LED OFF</button>
```

Comment: It no longer refreshes however, it is not sending the php state request. I shared the extra bit of the php code in the description. What can be done?

Comment: Test that the led.php page is working as you intend it to. Maybe the page is dying thats why its not working.

Comment: This is [the link to my website without the ajax code]( https://arduinowebconnect.000webhostapp.com/index.html) and this is the  [LED_data.txt portion](https://arduinowebconnect.000webhostapp.com/LED_data.txt) when you click LED ON, the LED_data.txt changes to 1 and when you click LED OFF, the LED_data.txt changes to 0. I don't know why as soon as the ajax code is added, the functions no longer work. Can you please help?

Comment: i have tested the code on my computer. it works fine using the code i posted. just one thing you need to do is remove the header function from led.php